# Strongswan Centos 7 Config Issue

Tags: centos, firewall, nat, strongswan, ikev2

I have a problem with configuring Strongswan on Centos 7 ! First please notice that I want to connect with only username and password and I don't want to import any profiles on my phone ! My server ip is 88.99.45.140 or hostname ik.xpdns.xyz and I want to setup Ikev2 vpn server on it ! Here is the tutorial I used : https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-ikev2-vpn-using-strongswan-and-letsencrypt-on-centos-7/

Here is my ipsec.config file :

```
#global configuration IPsec
#chron logger
config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no

#define new ipsec connection
conn hakase-vpn
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=@ik.xpdns.xyz
    leftcert=fullchain.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=10.15.1.0/24
    rightdns=1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
```

and here is my ipsec.secrets file :

```
# ipsec.secrets - strongSwan IPsec secrets file
@ik.xpdns.xyz : RSA "privkey.pem"
alid : EAP "123321"
```

here is my strongswan.conf file :

```
# strongswan.conf - strongSwan configuration file
#
# Refer to the strongswan.conf(5) manpage for details
#
# Configuration changes should be made in the included files

charon {
    load_modular = yes
    plugins {
        include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
    }
}

include strongswan.d/*.conf
```

and here are the firewall rules I entered :

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="esp" accept'
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="ah" accept'
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=500/udp
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=4500/udp
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service="ipsec"
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I have absolutely no clue why I'm getting error when my user want to connect to the server , It says remote host is behind NAT !!

```
Mar 20 11:19:10 ikev charon: 09[NET] received packet: from 89.165.18.30[500] to 88.99.45.140[500] (604 bytes)
Mar 20 11:19:10 ikev charon: 09[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(REDIR_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) ]
Mar 20 11:19:10 ikev charon: 09[IKE] 89.165.18.30 is initiating an IKE_SA
Mar 20 11:19:10 ikev charon: 09[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
Mar 20 11:19:10 ikev charon: 09[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
Mar 20 11:19:10 ikev charon: 09[NET] sending packet: from 88.99.45.140[500] to 89.165.18.30[500] (448 bytes)
Mar 20 11:19:40 ikev charon: 08[JOB] deleting half open IKE_SA with 89.165.18.30 after timeout
Mar 20 11:19:53 ikev systemd-logind: New session 8 of user root.
Mar 20 11:19:53 ikev systemd: Started Session 8 of user root.
Mar 20 11:53:22 ikev charon: 08[NET] received packet: from 89.165.18.30[500] to 88.99.45.140[500] (604 bytes)
Mar 20 11:53:22 ikev charon: 08[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(REDIR_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) ]
Mar 20 11:53:22 ikev charon: 08[IKE] 89.165.18.30 is initiating an IKE_SA
Mar 20 11:53:22 ikev charon: 08[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
Mar 20 11:53:22 ikev charon: 08[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
Mar 20 11:53:22 ikev charon: 08[NET] sending packet: from 88.99.45.140[500] to 89.165.18.30[500] (448 bytes)
```

I have been struggling for weeks with this and I give up ! I need help to solve this issue guys !

Comment: guys any help would be appreciated , I would even donate a few dollars to anyone who can set this up on my CentOS 7 server .

Comment: no one here can help with my situation?

Comment: It looks like the IKE_AUTH message is not getting through to the server. It is sent to port 4500 and could be quite large (and thus get fragmented). Check the client log, and firewall rules/stats, perhaps do some traffic captures to see where the packet(s) might get stuck. Apparently, both peers support IKEv2 fragmentation, but if there is still a fragmentation issue, try to reduce the fragment size.

Comment: hi @ecdsa , Is it possible to contact you directly via email or whatsapp? I'm looking for someone to set this up for me as I have tried everything and failed . Willing to donate some dollars to anyone who can set up the IKEV2 vpn server . If you can do this , please give me a way to contact you .